# Algoritmo para invertir el órden de los índices de un vector en filas específicadas

Tags: r

Tengo un archivo de datos cuyo ejemplo mínimo reproducible es [este](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e1853wkqw1dbiub/export.csv?dl=0).

El archivo contiene una variable denominada `Population_signals` cuyos campos contienen datos agrupados en forma de vectores con corchetes (e.g. [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9])

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna función en R que permita invertir el orden de lo índices de vectores, de tal manera que por ejemplo, si un vector es [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,9] la función devolviera [9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1].

El algoritmo me gustaría utilizarlo para cambiar el orden de los vectores de las filas impares de un dataframe. El resultado deseado con el dataframe compartido sería como sigue:

```
1   Population_signals
2   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
3   [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
4   [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]
5   [0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
7   [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una alternativa, similar a la de Patricio pero usando tidyverse. Modifica solamente las filas impares del data.frame.

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(Population_signals = c(
"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]",
"[2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]",
"[0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]",
"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0]",
"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]",
"[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]")) -> df

df %>%
   mutate(pop_invertida = str_remove_all(Population_signals, "\\[|\\]") %>%
                   str_split(., ", ") %>%
                   map( ~ .x[length(.x):1]) %>%  #Uso el índice para cambiar el orden. Debería funcionar para no numéricos.
                   map_chr( ~ paste0(.x, collapse = ", ")) %>%
                   paste0("[", ., "]")  #Fin tubería interna
          ) %>%  
   mutate(Population_signals = ifelse(1:n() %% 2 == 0, 
                                      pop_invertida,   #Si es impar uso la columna revertida
                                      Population_signals)) %>%
   select(-pop_invertida)
```

Resultado:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 1
  Population_signals             
  <chr>                          
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10]
2 [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2] 
3 [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0] 
4 [0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0]
6 [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @mpaladino

Answer (score 1):

El tema es que datos finalmente es el que buscas conseguir, ahora claramente es una columna "character" que hay que interpretarla como un vector para reversar el orden:

```
lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", '', df$Population_signals), ','),
       function(x) {rev(as.integer(x))})

[[1]]
 [1] 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[[2]]
 [1] 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2

[[3]]
 [1] 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0

[[4]]
 [1]  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[[5]]
 [1]  0  0 10  0  0  0  0  0  0  0

[[6]]
 [1] 0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 3 0
```

Con `gsub("\\[|\\]", '', df$Population_signals)`, quitamos los corchetes y con `strsplit()`, separamos la cadena por la `,` y generamos una lista de vectores, finalmente con `lapply()` aplicamos `rev(as.integer(x))`, es dcir, convertimos las cadenas en enteros y invertimos el orden y ya tenemos los datos interpretados y revertidos.

Si luego eventualmente queremos generar una columna similar a la original:

```
df$Population_signals_rev <- sapply(strsplit(gsub("\\[|\\]", '', df$Population_signals), ','), 
       function(x) { paste0("[",paste0(rev(as.integer(x)), collapse=', '), "]") })

df

               Population_signals          Population_signals_rev
1 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10] [10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
2  [2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8]  [8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2]
3  [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0]  [0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0]
4 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0] [0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
5 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0] [0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
6  [0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0]  [0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @Patricio Moracho. Excelente respuesta y muy didáctica, como siempre.